# Can I use the same Archive Manager database to archive historical versions of the same publication published to two different publication targets?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, database, archive-manager-1-sp3

I am in the process of creating the Archive Manager DB to setup Archive Manager for a website. This website can be published to two publication targets and I was wondering if archive manager makes any distinction per publication target. I know it does distinguish by url (preview.site.com vs live.site.com), but was wondering:

1. Is it possible at all to use the same db for both?
2. Most importantly, is it recommended to do so? What do best practices say?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There are modules of the Archive Manager that are installed and configured in the deployer and the storage layer. Since you will have a different deployer / storage for your preview vs. live website; there should NOT be any technical limitations per publication target. The resolution in the Archive Manager database, I believe, is done by the URL (and not relative); so there should not be any issues.

If we are using the same db for both of the publication targets; we will have to account for user experience who is using the Archive manager explorer. By using inclusion rules, I would recommend using a different Archive Manager explorer interface for preview vs. LIVE.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Shiva, I totally agree on separating the db per target, specially for the Production-Live target.

Comment: And after thinking about it, due to maintainability, I would probably recommend having separate am dbs per site too, so there's not archives of siteA.com in the same db of siteB.com